# Porque o upload de imagens para meu servidor DigitalOcean é tão lento?

Tags: java, upload

Estou rodando uma aplicação Java usando Play! Framework no meu droplet na DigitalOcean. Porém, ao fazer upload de imagens pelo navegador percebo que a requisição está muito lenta e o upload de uma imagem de ~2MB está demorando ~1-2 minutos para acontecer.

Alguém sabe o porque de acontecer esse problema?

Answer (score 2):

Fala aí.
Cara, na [comunidade](https://www.digitalocean.com/community) DO tem uns caras recomendando executar o comando `ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 10000` para forçar o aumento na taxa de upload para cada droplet que você possua.
Porém não há muitas informações a respeito de quais configurações o ambiente em que este comando foi realizado. Se vc tiver como testar numa droplet de testes blz.

Antes, talvez seja interessante testar a taxa de upload do seu provedor de internet, pois pode ocorrer de os servers da DO estarem aceitando mais do que seu upload pode enviar.

Faça uns testes em http://speedtest-nyc1.digitalocean.com/, ou nesta mesma página, escolha a região onde seu droplet esteja e refaça os testes de down e up do seu provedor de internet.

Em último caso, abra um ticket com eles, a equipe nas vezes que solicitei, sempre foi muito profissional, e mesmo com meu inglês sem vergonha, fui bem atendido.

PS: *Talvez seu droplet estava com uma interface de rede diferente de **eth0**, caso ocorra de ser, troque a interface para testar o comando do primeiro parágrafo.*